# How to include scope in function pointer

Tags: c++, lambda, scope, function-pointers

Consider a library function

`registerCallback(int event_type, void(*handler)())`

which registers a handler for some kind of event. I want to register several handlers using this function but include a 'scope' to it. An example would be a wrapper function like

`registerCallback2(int event_type, void* arg, void(*handler)(void*)`

which enables the registration of handlers that receive an additional argument.

I tried to use lambda expressions, but have soon learned that a lambda expression that captures something cannot be converted to a function pointer, and neither can be a class method, so a Class wrapper seems not to work as well.

Do you have any idea how this can be solved in a thread-safe way (can be called simultaneous from several threads)? The example should work with GCC 4.7.2 and Linux.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You have to interface with library that only has something like `registerCallback` and nothing like `registerCallback2`? If you could tell what library it is it might help you too.

Comment: yes, that's right. I want to create `registerCallback2` and the library only provides `registerCallback`

Comment: Then there is no to do this in standard C++, beside using global/thread-local variables. Try to make sure that you library doesn't allow state. You could also try some unportable trampoline tricks.

Comment: @zch: Or, to rephrase slightly, you can do this in standard C++ using global/thread-local variables. It's nasty but, if you really need to use such a broken API, it can be done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have made something similar using boost::function for enabling the callback. You could pass a shared weak pointer to your register and before calling it, verify if the pointer is still valid.

my call looks like this:

```
register_callback(EventManager::EVENT_IDENTIFIER, boost::bind(&MyClass::myCallback, this, _1))
```

EDIT:
Within this register_callback function (with is your registerCallback2) you can call registerCallback of the library, so that the scope can be handled.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this requires the function `registerCallback` to accept functors or boost::function constructs instead of a pure function pointer, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, after wrapping my head around it this will be a bit difficult. Can you determine within the callback what the calling "object" was? I mean an ID or something that can link the request to the result?

Comment: Unfortunately that's my problem: I can't

Comment: I do not know how the main library works. If the callbacks can be called any time, independent on the time the register was called, then it will be impossible to do multiple calls and link them to the caller. What you still can do is write a wrapper around it, which will do the call, wait for the callback, call your callback, do the next call, and so on. Then you could keep it "multithreaded" within your application, but synchronize the calls before passing it to the library.